# Scroll top +10 with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want that when the user clicks one button, he scrolls +10 pixels down. I can't use `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '10px'}, 300);` here, because it will just scroll +10px from the top and that's not what I need. Is it possible to do what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($(window).scrollTop() + 10) + 'px'}, 300);
```

Comment: course, I have to ask why just 10 pixels? If you have firebug or similar tool installed, run this jquery command on this very site and see just how little 10 pixels really is.

Comment: That's was just an example. :)

Comment: fair enough. did either of these answers help out?

Answer (score 3):

The `scrollTop()` jQuery function not only scrolls the page, but also returns the current scroll position.

To get the current scroll position, use `var y = $('body').scrollTop();` then use that to calculate the number you need (`y+10`).